# Help finding the limit of the sequence?

Tags: calculus

I was given the sequence $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{4}$,$\frac{1}{8}$, $\frac{1}{16},\ldots$ . I created an equation to represent the sequence $a_n=\dfrac{1}{2^{n+1}}$. Now how do I go about finding the limit?

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n=\frac{1}{2^n}$$
$$\implies \lim_{ n\to \infty}a_n=\lim_{ n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=0$$